# Cannot send authorization header with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, authorization

Below is my function for sending a request:

```
function invokeService() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var user = "User1";
                var pass = "Pwd1";


        var hash_str=make_base_auth(user, pass);

        // the post to your webservice or page
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', hash_str);
                },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + hash_str
            },
            url: "http://Servername/ProjName/TestService.svc/GetDetails/" + $('#itemid').val(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp"



        }); 
    });
}
```

I have tried different ways, by passing user name and password directly via something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    username: user,
    password: pass,
    ...
});
```

and by setting authorization header, but every tie I check it in Fiddler, in `Auth` section of the request it states "No authorization headerr is present". It just does not send it. Can anyone help me fix my authorization header?

Below is what shows up in Fiddler in a request header:

```
GET /projName/TestService.svc/GetDetails/ABC123?callback=jsonpxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1


Client
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

Transport
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: ServerName
```

Comment: I've found Safari strips the `Authorization` header set in an AJAX call. Perhaps IE is doing the same thing? Change the name of your header from `Authorization` to something else, and inspect the request do see if that header goes through. If so, IE has the same limitation the Safari has and you'll need to use a different header, but in the calling code and the receiving code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and works fine (relevant part of beforeSend callback):

```
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
                }
```

**btoa** encodes your sensitive data in the header.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it is not the encoding that is the problem, it is just that the header does not get sent

Comment: I understood, but I remember having the same problem when I tried to send user authentication the same way you doing.